# How do I make search less sensitive?

Tags: php

I made simple PHP code to search inside text file, it works!

But my problem is the search result is very text sensitive, for example If I want to search on "Iphone 4" and the text was "Iphone4" or "Iphone-4"
It will not appear in search result.
What should I add or modify to make it more flexible?

This is my code:

```
<?php

function searchID(Array $array, $value) 
    {   
        $idresult = "";
        foreach ($array as $subarray){ 
         if (isset($subarray[0]) && (substr($subarray[0], 0, strlen($value)) == $value) && $value!="") 
         { $idresult .= $subarray[0]." ".$subarray[2]." ".$subarray[1]."<br />";   }

         } 
         return $idresult;
    } 

// searchFirstName looks through the given $array and for each item that matches(even partially) 
// $value in the first name field it prints a table row of data, also returning a count of found items.
function searchFirstName(Array $array, $value) 
    {   
        $firstresult = "";
        foreach ($array as $subarray)
        {  
         if (isset($subarray[2]) && stristr($subarray[2],$value) && $value!=""){
             $firstresult .= $subarray[0]." ".$subarray[2]." ".$subarray[1]."<br />";   
             }
         }
             return $firstresult;
    } 


function searchLastName(Array $array, $value){   
        $lastresult = '';
        foreach ($array as $subarray){
         if (isset($subarray[1]) && stristr($subarray[1],$value) && $value!="") { $lastresult .= $subarray[0]." ".$subarray[2]." ".$subarray[1]."<br />";} 
             } return $lastresult;
}

$file = fopen("classlist.txt", "r");
$filestring = "";
$line_of_text ="";
while (!feof($file)) {
    $tempstring = fgets($file);
    $filestring .= $tempstring."<br />";
    $line_of_text .= $tempstring;
}
// populate $students array - line by line
$students = explode("\n", $line_of_text);
fclose($file);

// separate the ID, Last name and First name
foreach ($students as $key=>$value){
    $students[$key] = explode(",", $value);
}

$term = strip_tags(substr($_POST['search_term'],0, 100));

$string = '';
if ($term != "" && $term != " "){
switch ($_POST['field']) {
                case "fname":
                    $string .= searchFirstName($students, $term);
                    break;
                case "lname":
                    $string .= searchLastName($students, $term);
                    break;
                case "id":
                    $string .= searchID($students, $term);
                    break;
            }
}
if ($string != "") echo $string;
else echo '<div class="alert_yellow">No results found</div>';

?>
```

The text is sorted inside the text file like this:

```
9810,APPLE_Iphone_4_BW2,pdf
9810,APPLE_Iphone4_BW2,pdf
9810,APPLE_Iphone 4BW2,pdf
9810,APPLE_Iphone_4_BW2,pdf
```

**When I search on "iphone4" the result only show "9810,APPLE_Iphone4_BW2,pdf" instead of all 4 lines! that's my problem!**

Comment: Possibly a regex / [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) to look things up, after transforming `iphone 4` into `/iphone\W?4/i` for example. The current code is impossible to follow for anyone else; so perhaps even consider a database.

Comment: I just edit my qustion, I hope it's clear now, sorry for my english

Comment: The MySQL FULLTEXT indexes make searches really powerful. You can implement that in PHP as well, but it's not trivial by far. You basically have to break up the text and the search string in terms, maybe even define synonyms for certain terms, or compare using soundex, to also cover for certain spelling errors. The more powerful you want it to be, the harder it is. If you don't need all that, I think the very simplest version would be to remove all non-alphanumeric characters in both the text and the search string before you search.